# Evitar el autoscroll del navegador al actualizar un div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy implementando una página web de contenido dinámico. En concreto, tengo un "div" el cual voy actualizando su contenido de la siguiente manera:

Este es el "div":

```
<div id="informationONDevices"></div>
```

Procedo a borrar su contenido:

```
document.getElementById("informationONDevices").innerHTML = "";
```

Finalmente, voy metiéndole "divs" (el código que va a continuación está dentro de un bucle):

```
var element  = document.createElement("div");

element.innerHTML = "<h3>Dades de la sonda amb ID: " + this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('addONDevices')[count1].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " i Alias: " + this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('aliasONDevices')[count1].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</h3>" + "<br><br>"
+ "<span class='title'>Actual</span><br>";

document.getElementById("informationONDevices").appendChild(element);
```

El problema es que cada vez que se actualiza el contenido del "div" la página hace autoscroll y no se queda en el sitio en el que estaba. ¿Alguna solución? He estabo buscando y probando bastantes cosas y ninguna me ha servido.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Después de estar horas buscando información he decidido ir probando cosas.

Aquí la solución:

```
var oldPositionSB = window.pageYOffset;

document.getElementById("informationONDevices").innerHTML = "";

…

document.getElementById("informationONDevices").appendChild(element);

window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + (oldPositionSB - window.pageYOffset));
```